# How to match <elementName> [linebreak]</elementName> using Notepad++ version 7.0

Tags: notepad++

I want to perform a search operation using Notepad++ editor.

```
<elementName>
</elementName>
```

I have made use of extended search, but it doesn't return with any matching record.

```
<elementName>\r\n</elementName>
```

also using regular expressions

```
<elementName>[\r\n]+</elementName>
```

I have open this `.xaml` file at `Notepad++ 7.0+` editor. Correct me where I am making mistake or suggest a better approach to do so.

**Edit** 
I have found the solution and find it below at the answers section, please.

Comment: Yeah I'm pretty sure that will work just fine, it's one I use on a regular basis. There might be something else wrong with your file.

Answer (score 0):

> The `\s` `shorthand class` helps to match `whitespace
>   character(s)`  This `\s` matches
>   a space, a tab, a line break, or a form feed.

`<elementName>\s+</elementName>`

At `Notpad++` `version 7.0` you should see the follow these steps to match all whitespace(s)

Step 1: Press key combination `Ctrl+f` (a 'find and replace' dialog box will be displayed.)

Step 2: Select `regular expression option` and click on 'Find' button.

On result pane you will find a stack of matched records, if successful.

Hope it helps!

Comment: Stating *"I have tried this ... All suggestions are welcome, though"* makes it look like this is another question. But in the question itself you say that you *"have found the solution and find it below at the answers section"*. If this is indeed the answer then please [edit] it to clearly describe what works and say that it works. Please do not leave this answer looking like another question.

Comment: @AdrianHHH Thanks for the tip. I hope the answer follows the standard of SO community now.